# FreeIPA host with dynamic IP

Tags: redhat, freeipa

I'm trying to logon to Windows with FreeIPA User. Everything went fine when i created IPA host with specific ---ip-address but what if my host(windows machine) do not have static IP? i know after first succesfull login to windows the login credentials are stored local, but it takes some time when i try login to windows without having right IP. Do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FreeIPA does not officially support login to Windows with IPA users.

Answering your question about IP address, if you are using dynamic IP addresses, you need to set up a method to dynamically update hostname information when IP address is allocated and changed. It is not possible to do so from Windows side right because FreeIPA does not support it.

If you want to have Windows machines enrolled into some domain, you are better to use Samba AD instead. That will allow to dynamically update Windows machine details in Samba AD as well.